# Angular-CLI Tour of Heroes example code (getHeroes) meaning

Tags: javascript, angular-cli

Here's the code to getHeroes()

```
getHeroes(): void {
this.heroService.getHeroes()
   .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}
```

What my understanding is getHeroes() function:
getHeroes() dont't take any param and return void. It will call another function is heroService with the same name getHeroes(). subscribe() is called so heroService.getHeroes() is executed. Inside subscribe(), this.heroes = heroes means write received heroes to this.heroes. What's the first heroes keyword do? (heroes => ...)

Answer (score 2):

I have C/C++ background, so below link is very helpful in understanding java script arrow function.
[javascript.info, arrow function](https://javascript.info/function-expressions-arrows)

The mening of the code above is subscribe() function's parameter is a function. And the function take heroes as parameter and execute the expression to right of arrow sign.

Answer (score 0):

its an arrow function that will be called when the response is ready, it takes one parameter `heroes` from the service function and assign it to the variable `this.heroes`

Answer (score 0):

**Observables**

The `getHeroes()` function returns an [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) *observable* which has got a `subscribe()` member function. Observables are a stream of data. So they can push data to all its *subscribers*. This is why you have to subscribe (and unsubscribe) from observables. The first parameter of the subscribe function is the data stream (function), the second optional parameter an error (function) and the third parameter is a callback function which runs when the observable completes.

You should read about observables in the rxjs docs, they are really powerful.

**Lambda (or arrow) functions**

The phrase in the `subscribe` function is called lambda function. It is a inline function which does not overwrite the `this` statement, means you have access to the parents class members in this function. They are available in two different types, the first type is e.g. the usage of the JS array `map` function in the following way.

```js
const property1Array = array1.map(entry => entry.property1);
```

This is actually a shorthand for

```js
const property1Array = array1.map((entry) => {
  return entry.property1;
})
```